# Expo Document Picker disables documents on Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api, expo

I am trying to implement a Document Picker using Expo v32. The component opens, closes and uploads properly. However, Android's document picker only allows me to choose images.

I have tried specifying the MIME types for files: `application/msword, application/vnd.ms-excel` for example. But this still doesn't work. I also tried setting `{ type: "*/*" }` in the getDocumentAsync call but with no luck.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { DocumentPicker } from 'expo';

import { TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native'

import { postDocument } from '../../../actions/deal'

class AddFiles extends Component {
  _pickDocument = async () => {
    // Get the document from picker and upload with API
    let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({});
    if(result.type == 'success'){
      this.props.postDocument(this.props.dealId, result)
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._pickDocument}>
        <Text>
          Add Files
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({ postDocument }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AddFiles)
```

I would expect to see all possible files available for choosing, but I can only pick images.

[image]

Any idea on what I'm missing?

Comment: What happens if you explicitly give the file types for `.docs` and `.xls`?

Answer (score 1):

So this code actually works but there is one catch:

Expo's Document Picker - by default - **does not** allow Google Docs, Sheets or Slides to be added.

All of those files which are "disabled" are Google Drive files. Once you convert them to proper `.docx` or `.xls` then they will work.

To add google drive files, you need to specify their MIME types:

```
application/vnd.google-apps.document
application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet
application/vnd.google-apps.presentation
```

All Google Drive Mime types are here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types